# Sort ItemsControl from bottom to top

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need this table to be listed from bottom to top. 0's should be at the bottom.
Did a lot of google search, but the most suggestions I found are using ListBox or overriding the UniformGrid (which btw I also tried). Non of these suggestions worked for me.

```
<Window x:Class="Double_ItemsControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Double_ItemsControl"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

   <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
   </Window.DataContext>

   <Grid>
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OuterList}">
           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                               <UniformGrid Columns="1" />
                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <UniformGrid Columns="6" />
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       </ItemsControl>
   </Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Double_ItemsControl
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<int> InnerList { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> OuterList { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            InnerList = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 0,1,2,3,4 };
            OuterList = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 35; i++)
            {
                 if (i % 5 == 0)
                 {
                     OuterList.Add(InnerList);
                 }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

BTW: I need to use two ItemControls.

Comment: Have you tried sorting the ObservableCollection in the opposite order before?

Comment: You can  defined the `CollectionViewSource` in XAML and can `SortDescription` with `Direction` as desc.

Comment: Hi @user1672994 thank you for your suggestion. Ill try that out

Comment: You might be able to return a sorted iEnumerable and bind to that.  But not sure it will update when you add or remove from the ObservableCollection.